# What are differences between error_reporting(E_ALL) and error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)

Tags: php, error-reporting

Could anyone explain differences between `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` ?

I noticed that when I change from `E_ALL` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`, an error which I was hacking, disappears.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

E_ALL is "everything"

E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE is "everything except notices"

Notices are the least-urgent kinds of messages.  But they can be very useful for catching stupid programmer mistakes, like trying to read from a hash with a non-existent key, etc.

(To understand the syntax, read up on bitwise operators)

Answer (score 5):

E_ALL would should all the error and warning and notice - **everything**

E_NOTICE is a special error level, showing things that won't produce error but are not good or gonna be obsolete in future release of PHP. The notice error level is meant to encourage best practices.

Also it should be `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` to report everything except notice.

You are advice during development to set the error reporting to E_ALL and fix all the notice errors.

a look in the [manual](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) would give much more details.

Answer (score 3):

E_ALL is a flag 
E_NOTICE is a flag as well

so when you do bitwise operation of ~ which is NOT you'll exclude E_NOTICE from E_ALL

Under the hood following happens

in decimal

```
E_ALL = 32767 
E_NOTICE = 8
```

they are power of 2

bitwise

```
E_ALL    = 111111111111111
E_NOTICE = 000000000001000
```

result of NOT will be

```
111111111110111
```

then php can internally check if notices are ON with &(AND) operator

```
111111111110111
000000000001000
```

`1 & 0 = 0` it means it is turned off. If however you didn't use ~ NOT then it would be `1 & 1 = 1` it means that flag is SET

There are other options for example OR to turn on the flag, or XOR to change the flag to opposite state.  Basically, this is how flags work.

Comment: showing this in binary for the win.